# Why do they sell luggage in airports?

Tags: luggage, airports, factoids, shopping

It seems that in almost every airport I'm in, there are luggage stores behind security. How often do people get to the airport carrying handfuls of clothes and needing something to put them in? I realize that there are limited cases in which they could be useful, but why are they so prolific and how do they remain profitable?

Comment: They sell clothes too so you can fill your brand new bag…

Comment: It's for people who don't realize what a good ideas it is to check their kids in a suitcase until they've already arrived at the airport. Most of the last minute checked bags you see at the end of the jetway aren't full of clothes, you know.

Comment: Because not every traveller is as cheap and resistant to buying any over-priced product that airports sell. Having more money than most does not seem to correlate with sensible buying decisions.

Comment: Supply and demand. People want to buy luggage in airports. The question should be "Why do people buy luggage in airports?"

Comment: Customer officers have a long track record breaking locks of luggage. you could buy new luggage after this.

Comment: most duty free shops now can arrange for delivery of your purchase, so you don't have to carry it with you. Works for the cars you can buy in some duty free areas as well :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Even though the people who walk past are unlikely to be want to buy a suitcase *right now*, they are still the target demographic. How many other locations are there in a city where you can open a store where 100% of the people that walk past are people that travel by air, and thus the type of people that will be in the market for your products?

How many non-airport locations around an area like the San Francisco Bay Area would you need to open a store in order to pretty much guarantee that every person who flies internationally at least once a year walks in front of your store?  A dozen?  A few dozen?  How about if you do it in an airport?  Perhaps 2? (eg, SFO has 2 international terminals).

Some of the luggage shops you find in airports are for a particular brand.  eg, there is a Tumi store in Newark airport.  Even if that store was to never actually sell a single piece of luggage, they are building their brand and allowing people to see and try their product range before going home and ordering the same pieces from their website or from another store - all of which works in their favor.

The remainder of the stores generally sell high-end luggage which they would likely be able to ship to a home location if someone purchased something and was unable to take it with them or collect on their return trip.

At the end of the day, don't think of these as luggage stores, just think of them as high-end retail, marketing to a demographic that frequents airports (high wealth/travelers).

Comment: I am not convinced by your introductory paragraph. The point of the question is that in airport suitcase stores, nearly 100% of the people that walk past are people that already have a suitcase, who have already checked in that suitcase and are thus in no position to even repack their stuff and throw away the old one. The rare exception may be people who bring suitcases through security as handluggage (unfortunately, some airports still allow this) and replace those, or indeed (as suggested in the comments) buy so much stuff that they need another bag or suitcase.

Comment: In all, the non-airport locations (preferrably close to housing areas) seem like the much better spot for finding a maximum number of people who will be in the market for suitcases than the security area of an airport. Compare it to offering an (additional!) full meal to restaurant guests after they have ordered. Yes, you'll find 100% of people who are willing to eat in a restaurant, but at the same time, hardly any of them are *then and there* in need of any meal because they are already about to get one.

Comment: You would think so.  However long research into marketing and psychology, ultinmately backed by "how much gets sold" shows that advertising, even if not close to the decision or purchase, is still effective.  This is how brand advertising works.  As long as you know and recognize the brand the _next_ time you are in the market, then the purpose is achieved.  Given that the audience that walks by travels by plane, it is a great subset to advertise to in this way. "Today's advertising, Tomorrow's customers."

Comment: Also think "Goodyear Blimp".  The idea isn't that you buy tires on the way home from the ball game... but most families at the ball game _will_ likely be buying tires in the next year or two.  Hmmm, which brand to buy, what seems safe and familiar and has good memories...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper All of my local shopping malls require you to be dressed when you go there, yet they contain countless shops that sell clothes. How stupid is that? 100% of the people there already have clothes, so why are they trying to sell them more?!?

Comment: @Doc: Because those people have ample capacity for carrying the bought extra clothes in their nearby cars, or will head home right after shopping anyway and bring the extra clothes there. That is in contrast to people at airports, particularly in the security area, who are about to embark on a lengthy journey and will have to carry everything they buy in their hand luggage during at least the upcoming leg of their journey.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: I did not mean to reject the paragraph explaining the advertisement value for brands with the fictional "Tumi" example; I was just not convinced by the initial explanation that sounded like many travellers buying right there.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't think it was ever implied that "many travelers [would be] buying right there", only that the travelers who pass by are the ones most likely to (at some point) be in the market for one.  If you put a luggage store in the middle of a city, you'd likely go out of business just as easily as you suggest one in an airport would because lets face it, how many people really need to buy luggage?  Especially if you're in a smaller city/town.  How else do you get name recognition - given the product has such a small demographic that commercials are near worthless.

Comment: (Just to avoid any confusion, the "Doc" that left the previous comment is NOT the same user as the "Doc" that answered the question, or left the earlier comment above)

Comment: @Doc: Ok, that gets clearer with the newly added sentence "Even though the people who walk past are unlikely to be want to buy a suitcase right now, they are still the target demographic." Before that sentence was edited in, the answer did sound a lot like exactly that was implied, that many travelers buy right there.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper there's car dealerships behind customs on some major airports. Those customers aren't likely to carry their new BMW or Merc as cabin luggage, are they?

Comment: @jwenting: There are two kinds of car dealerships (or in general, stores for more expensive, large items). One has some cars on store, to buy one, you hand over money, and drive away with the car right away. The other one may have some cars for looking at right there, but buying usually means signing a contract and thereby placing an order for a product that gets delivered some days or weeks later. I am not at all surprised to find the latter type behind customs in airports, but the former type would (at least without the explanations here) appear just as pointless to me as the suitcase store.

Answer (score 23):

Setting aside the people who suddenly need more or different suitcases, an airport is one of the few places where you feel dissatisfied with the suitcases you have. While they're sitting in your closet, they're fine. You've used them for years and they work. But for the hour or two after you've packed them, lugged them from the car into the airport, and checked them, you know everything you hate about them: they're too big, they don't hold enough, they're too heavy, you don't like the wheels, the handle is too short, the color is old fashioned or the same as everyone else's, you name it. And you're surrounded by other people's suitcases to feel jealous of.

And now you have an hour to kill and nothing to do except pay too much for coffee or use up some of your reading material, and here's a store full of glorious suitcases. Maybe they have one that you were ogling somebody else use just moments ago. You can lift them, open and close them, work the handles, and compare in your head to the hated suitcase you just checked in. Maybe you'll buy on the spot and have them shipped home to await your return. More likely you'll take notes and order them online when you get back. If the store is part of a chain, they don't care which you do, this location can be more of a showroom than an actual selling things store. Of course, if you're carrying multiple carryon bags that you don't like, you might actually buy a replacement on the spot and swap things out and throw the old ones away. But the chain can make a ton of money if you never buy a full size suitcase there, as long as you buy one eventually. Heck, even if you don't go it, if you walked by and saw the name and saw that the suitcases didn't appear to be crap, they may have a financial case for that being worth it.

Comment: Your second paragraph was exactly what I was thinking of! Just the fact that you have a few hours to kill helps them make a lot of dough. No. of I've entered a suitcase store in a market = 0, No. of times I've entered one in the airport = Uncountable

Comment: I bought a backpack in such a store once. I was travelling for one side of earth to the opposite and for some reason decided that taking a few plastic bags with me to the cabin would be a good idea. I quickly changed my mind and they got a sale.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I have indeed frequently felt dissatisfied with my suitcases while at airports for many years and often had a lot of idling time, though I would never have had the idea to check out a suitcase store in an airport and would always walk past them as airport stores (or in general, stores with little alternative to go to) probably try to rip off customers. Just having a look and finding the same suitcase elsewhere for a more reasonable price sounds like a worthwhile suggestion, though.

Comment: Single-letter typo, too small for me to correct: "even if you don't go it" should be "... go in". (Please feel free to flag this comment as obsolete once corrected.)

Answer (score 11):

Suitcases may fail in transit. That's a built-in market for replacements.

Comment: You're unlikely to know this before you get to the baggage claim though, by which time it's too late for duty-free shopping.

Comment: @jpatokal Yeah, but you'd need to buy one on the way home.

Comment: ... and many folks care less about duty-free than "I need something that isn't going to fall apart again on the return trip... oh, look, that would do the job."

Comment: @starsplusplus I don't follow you. Suppose my suitcase gets trashed by the baggage handlers on my outbound flight. While I'm sitting in the departure lounge waiting for my outbound, I don't know my bag's been trashed (or it's not even been trashed yet). By the time I'm sitting in the departure lounge for my return flight, it's too late because I've already checked my luggage, either in the trashed suitcase or in one I bought somewhere other than the airport.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this fully explains it but the shopping area has certainly become an important revenue stream for many airports. I know several airports that have been redesigned to force passengers to pass in front of as many shops as possible, with S-shaped corridors and no short-cuts. Consequently, they sell a lot of things that most people don't *need* right there (and people buy them!). They are designed as a shopping location, not as a way to provide necessities so whether passengers already have a suitcase is not particularly relevant.

My local airport even advertises a service by which they keep what you bought until you return. As a matter of fact, I happen to know that they do sell a lot of bags so that in itself explains why these shops are profitable. Presumably, it works because airports are places where many affluent travelers have to wait or at least walk through every day.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: I think this barely answers the question. The question is *not* why there are any stores in the airport or within the security area, the question is why *suitcases* are sold within the security area.

Comment: As for keeping what you bought until you return, doesn't that mean you have to stay in the security area after arrival (which is hardly possible in most airports I have seen; you are immediately guided through a triple door to leave the security area after unboarding), or do they bring it to some other place in the non-security area where you can pick up your belongings?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper What I am saying is that some airports have become shopping centers that sell everything (and not merely stuff travelers are likely to need at the very moment they are waiting for their flight), which does answer the question (they sell suitcases because that's one of the products you would expect in a department store, you don't need any more reason than that).

Comment: Regarding the layout, I guess it varies, I know a few airports where you are not guided through anything but have to go through the airside departure lounge/waiting area/shopping center to reach the border control/luggage claim area (e.g. Schiphol, which is the one I had in mind when writing the answer). In Geneva arriving passengers are not only walking past the shops, you literally have to go through the aisles of a duty-free shop, which I guess is also another consequence of the trend I am highlighting.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Incidentally, both my answer and Doc's make essentially the same points and are arguably a bit speculative but I can tell you for a fact that airport shops do sell a lot of bags and suitcases (I happened to have worked briefly for a high-end retailer with shops both at an airport and on main street). I don't know if this explanation is the right one but a discussion predicated on the assumption that people won't buy suitcases in airports is not very interesting because they simply do.

Comment: Interesting. Why do they buy suitcases in airports, then?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper See [this picture](http://www.carjet.com/files/Geneva,%20Switzerland%20-%20Duty%20Free%20shop%20on%20arrival%20-%20Geneva%20Airport%20and%20car%20hire.jpg). The dark grey path is the *only* way to the luggage claim area…

Comment: Concerning the picture: That looks nice. I hope more airports get built like that. So often I have seen something in an airport that I wanted to buy (not one of the overpriced items that you can get outside, but something of the souvenir stuff that is available (almost) only in airport stores), but did not because I did not want to add it to my inflight luggage. Invariably, in various airports, I had no chance of getting to that store on the way back any more, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Like I said, the best I can think of is that people have time to shop, money to spend and generally travel a lot so might be interested in suitcases but I don't really know more than that. (Also, I am not sure what the proper English terminology is but I am talking more about middle-size [Tumi products](http://tuckstuff.com/images/products/detail/tumi_detail.jpg), not bulky plastic suitcases).

Answer (score 3):

It's straightforward ... people have an old, rubbishy, carry-on or roll-on case...

They stop at the samsonite shop, they buy a fancy new cabron-fiber one...

they transfer their stuff to the new one and throw out the old one, or, just take both.

If you watch the shops in question, you'll see this happening all the time.

Also very commonly (I've done this, actually a number of times) someone will have **no** roll-on with them; you might be carrying say a couple of paperbacks, a shopping bag, and a laptop or something - so you go right ahead and buy a new cabron-fiber roll-on.

Note that the shops you describe **only sell carry on styles.  If they sold hold-luggage, then just as you say** it would be illogical!

Comment: At least some do sell hold luggage too...

Comment: Most sell full-sized luggage as well.

Comment: @Araucaria - FTW !!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simply becuase there have been instances of people who had their luggages broken in transit from home to airport or between transfers.  Why else?

Comment: It can't be that. If your luggage was broken in transit to the airport, allowing you to buy new luggage only after you've checked in the broken luggage doesn't help. And if your bag gets broken by the baggage handlers, you don't know about that while you're sitting in the departure lounge.

Comment: Not all luggage is checked...